# Python string invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
onedata = str("& "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"")
print (onedata)
```

Im trying to run it but it says:

```
    onedata = str("& "C:\Program Files\test.test")
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have 3 sets of " within your brackets

Comment: It looks obvious where the issue is, it's where the error shows you. You have 3 `"`. Here is the problem you are missing a `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed the string before you should have. I'm guessing you want the literal `"` in the string, so you need this:

```
onedata = str("& \"C:\\Program Files\\test.test")
```

`\"` makes a literal `"` character. and `\\` makes a literal `\` character. This is so that the compiler doesn't get confused between the literal meaning of a character and its syntactic meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the second double quotes with `\`. Or you can use single outer quotes:

```
onedata = str('& "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"')

print(onedata)

& "C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

put a back lash behind the second ( " ) to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are excellent, but they don't mention another solution that I personally find easier than using escape characters. In Python, you can use single quotes ('') or double quotes ("") for a string, and if you want to use a double quote inside the string, you can use single quotes to denote your string. Example:

```
'This is " a string'
```

is the same as:

```
"This is \" a string"
```